# Word (or phrase) for phrases that are examples of what they describe

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word (or phrase) for phrases that are examples of what they describe? For example, "You the verb" to tell someone they forgot a verb in an online posting, or "spacesmakethingseasiertoread".

Comment: I think it's called an oddlywordedquestionneedingbetter .

Comment: A common example is "STOP USING ALL CAPS!"

Comment: There's also "onomatopoeia", when a word phonetically sounds like what it describes. Such as "oink", "meow" or "quack".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most common, and most commonly understood, term is [*self-reference*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-reference), or *self-referential* if you're after an adjective.

A subset of that is [*autograms*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autogram), "sentences that describe themselves in the sense of providing an inventory of their own characters". Examples are "This sentence has exactly six words" or "This sentence employs seven e's".

For single words rather than phrases, there's also the term [*autological*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word). Textbook examples of this include "polysyllabic", "pentasyllabic", "short", "sesquipedalian", and "noun".

Lastly, there's the term [*iconicity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconicity)
that generally describes "the conceived similarity or analogy between the form of a sign (linguistic or otherwise) and its meaning". Examples include the word "bed", which some might note looks like a bed, or "looooong", made very long on purpose. Some poets, notably e e cummings, make deliberate use of visual iconicity, though auditory iconicity is more common (think [*onomatopoeias*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia)). Wikipedia provides this nice example of spatial iconicity:

> For instance, in Cummings' grasshopper poem ("r-p-o-p-h-e-s-s-a-g-r") the word *arriving* begins on the far right of the poem with the "a," the "r" is near the middle of the poem, and the rest of the word is on the left of the poem. The reader must travel a great distance across the poem, therefore, in order to "arrive".

Comment: Thank you, this was very thorough. _Autological_ and _iconicity_ come closest to what I wanted.

Comment: I believe that "self-reflexive" is sometimes used in philosophy to describe this characteristic.

Comment: The Wikipedia reference defines self-reference: Self-reference is a concept that involves referring to oneself/back to the referent or one's/the referent's own attributes, characteristics, or actions. It can occur in language, logic, mathematics, philosophy, and other fields. [adjusted, as 'oneself' hardly applies to say a step in a mathematical proof]

Answer (score 3):

**[Autological](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autological)**

> *adjective*
>   possessing the property it describes.
>   <sub>*(definition from [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autological))*</sub>

Although it is usually used to describe words, it can also apply to phrases or sentences.

([This related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169631/is-there-a-term-for-a-word-thats-recursive-in-its-meaning-see-example-for-cla) may also add some color.)