# Is there a term for a word that's recursive in its meaning? (see example for clarification)

Tags: terminology

For example, when someone uses the word "pedantic," he actually comes off as a pedant. Putting aside my opinion that "pedantic" is, in itself, pedantic, along with the obvious irony, is there a word, expression, or phrase that captures this sentiment?

I will edit my post accordingly if I am being unclear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can I clarify - do you mean specifically with respect to "pedantic", or do you mean any other word that behaves similarly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little bit complicated to me, but do you mean a *[self-referencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-reference)* word?

If so, then it is usually called an [autological word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word) or an autonym.

---

**[Autogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autogram)** - A sentence that describes itself in the sense of providing an inventory of its own characters.

> This sentence has five words.
>
> This sentence contains nine syllables.

---

**Reflexive** (sentence)

A sentence where the subject and object are the same (Sources: Reflexive [verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_verb), [pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_pronoun)).

> The man washed himself.

---

**[Hofstadster's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter%27s_law)**

Hofstadter's law is a self-referential time-related adage, coined by Douglas Hofstadter and named after him.

> Any task you're planning to complete will always take longer than expected - even when Hofstadter's law is taken into account. **Even if you know a project will overrun, and build that knowledge into your planning, it'll simply overrun your new estimated finish time, too**, Hofstadter says.

(Source: [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2008/aug/02/healthandwellbeing.psychology))

---

[Post hoc ergo propter hoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc)

Latin for *after this, therefore because of this*. It means a logical fallacy (of the questionable cause variety) that states "Since event Y followed event X, event Y must have been caused by event X." Sometimes shortened **post hoc**.

> The server was working fine until you started working here. Therefore, you must be the reason why it's broken.

---

**[Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Recursion_in_language)**

Recursion is the process of repeating items in a self-similar way. (Warning: Has many applications outside of language as well.)

> To understand recursion, you must understand recursion.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. Would it be appropriate to ask, as a follow up question, other examples/best examples of self referencing words? I'm actually more interested in this question. I'm new to these forums and am unsure if open-ended/subjective questions such as this are allowed.

Comment: @njboot The links I gave you will perhaps answer most of your questions. I would also peek into *reflexive* words, *recursion* and *post hoc ergo propter hoc* (all from the Wiki links).

Comment: Perhaps Tucker you could include a few in your post for those not inclined to visit Wikipedia? The best answers are self-contained, but bravo all the same!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Fine. Only because it's you.

Comment: Given the subject matter of this forum, perhaps it's not surprising that *sesquipedalian* comes to mind.

Comment: @ErikKowal I thought about adding that, but it's too niche. Also, *Ouroboros* and that lore could apply as well (from an etymological perspective). Could a word therefore be *ouroboric*?

Comment: You think we are too ompahaloscopic here? C'mon, man, you should be proud!  :-) As for *ouroboric* -- I like it. It seems to perfectly encapsulate the idea in a very visual way. In fact, you have like-minded company: see http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ouroboric

Comment: @ErikKowal Ha! Wow. I didn't even think that was a thing. You, sir, have officially made my day.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  :-) What probably *didn't* make anyone's day is my lousy typing -- that should of course have read *omphaloscopic*, i.e. 'navel-gazing'.

Comment: @ErikKowal Eh, no need to worry about that. I didn't notice it until you pointed it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Precisian**: [a person who is strict and precise in observing rules or customs, esp. of religion; specif., a 16th- or 17th-cent. English Puritan](http://www.yourdictionary.com/precisian)

**Micrologist**: [excessive attention to petty details or distinctions.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/micrology)

**Dryasdust**: [an imaginary and tediously thorough literary authority cited by Sir Walter Scott to present background information in his novels; thereafter, a derisory term for anyone who presents historical facts with no feeling for the personalities involved.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dryasdust)

Answer (score -1):

Subject - adjective relationship?
A pedant is pedantic?
Obviousness? A pedant is pedantic?

Captain obvious?